# the relation between popularity and competition in SEO field

Tags: seo

what is the relation between popularity and competition in SEO field?
i don't mean the formula.i mean the conceptional relation.
i mean can we say more competition cause more popularity or viseversa,more popularity cause more competition?

more competition about a topic means it is general that many sites talk about it and so maybe more people use the web for finding information about that topic and this cause more popularity.
on the other side,if more people search a special term on the web means there is some need for that topic and this cause site owner to talk about that topic to attract more visitors to their site and it cause growing competition.

what is your idea? am i think wrong?

Comment: not programming related?

Comment: @klez: sorry,but what do you mean?

Comment: that this is a programming question site, and I don't see how your question is programming related. don't take me wrong, it's an interesting question. it just doesn't fit here

Comment: yes,you are right,but i was thinking about that relation and couldn't get a conclusion and wanted a quick answer.here is the only place i know that always has some online people to answer questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be very hard to find any meaningful data on this, but this is how I see it and this is how I suggest these things to any client I visit.

If a subject is popular there will be more competition as it will be linked to frequently, and these pages would obtain link value for these terms within anchor text. Also, if a subject is popular it can be assumed that more people will want to search for it.

Obviously, if there is more competition then it's harder to become the best resource on Google. As it's typical for people to link to the best possible pages the best way to become popular in a field with lots of competition is to make your website the best possible resource for users; over a set period users will visit your website and those that like what they see will link to it.

As a result, the way to become popular in a field with lots of competition is to create the best possible web pages for that given subject. Naturally, there may be lots of competition in areas that aren't popular, but the data is already out there through Google and Yahoo tools to gauge what is popular and what isn't. It's just a matter of building your resources and being patient enough to become popular.